# RSSI of CLBeacon from a dictionary return nil

Tags: swift, dictionary, ibeacon

I have a dictionary that has as key a UDID and as value a CLBeacon. When I try to access the RSSI of the CLBeacon it returns nil but if I print the whole dictionary I see the CLBeacon and the RSSI value.

[CLBeacon dictionary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0TsJh.png)

let beaconDict = viewContr.beaconsDict as NSDictionary

```
    for (key, value) in beaconDict {
        let beacon = value as? CLBeacon
        let rssi = beacon?.rssi
        print("key=\(key), value=\(rssi)")
    }
    print("The dictionary is: \(beaconDict))")
}
```

Comment: did you try to print other values other than rssi? UUID, minor, major etc. Looks like casting to CLBeacon fails for some reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value was returning an NSArray.
Changing the below worked.

```
let beacon = value as? CLBeacon
```

to

```
let array = value as! NSArray
let beacon = array.firstObject as? CLBeacon
```